# ValueError: Shapes (None, 6) and (None, 5) are incompatible

Tags: keras, neural-network, sequential

i am trying to train my Sequential model but something goes wrong:

```
aspect_categories_model = Sequential()
aspect_categories_model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(6000,), activation='relu'))
aspect_categories_model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
aspect_categories_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

when try to predict value with:
`aspect_categories_model.fit(aspect_tokenized, dummy_category, epochs=5, verbose=1).` It got me a value error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 6) and (None, 5) are incompatible
```

the code for dummies is:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import to_categorical

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_category = label_encoder.fit_transform(dataset.aspect_category)
dummy_category = to_categorical(integer_category)
```

the labels are 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape of `dummy_category` is `(batch_size, 6)` and the output shape of the model is `(batch_size, 5)`.

Try changing the number of neurons in the final layer.

```
aspect_categories_model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
```

If you have only 5 categories for prediction then you have made some mistake in computing your `dummy_category` variable.

Comment: ok thank's it fix the issue but yes I have only 5 categories. I use this code for the dummies:from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import to_categorical

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_category = label_encoder.fit_transform(dataset.aspect_category)
dummy_category = to_categorical(integer_category)

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you tried to generate  `dummy_category` along with the labels you have?

Comment: Add sample data that produces 6 categories. ie. single row of data

Comment: Add data from the `dataset` variable. If possible add code that I can run on my machine reproduce your issue.